# need help replacing image in dll file C++ gui

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll

ok what i want to do is make a program with button witch i have done and use a dll form windows in this case its called resources.dll its from new blue effects and i want to change logo image on a dialog box how would i go around doing this

ok this is new to me dont say to me its advance i know it is just need someone to explain or give me some code and tell me how to implant it into a button im using gui intaface on vb

so one i have a resources.dll file

2 i want to change a image in this dll file using c++ gui witch is already done

3 all i need is some code and a little explication on how to use it we all have to start some ware i know the basics of this but videos dont quite cover what i want to do not asking you to do it for me im just asking for some help with this i will add your name on my product :) thank you 
elfenliedtopfan5

images on what i mean 
[image: new blue effects dialog with image i want to replace]

[image: vb gui]

[image: dir of the dll]

Comment: It's not difficult to tell what is asked here. The question is quite clear. Some people have chosen to display their disposition to think that their lack of understanding means that others don't make sense, by choosing to vote to close this question as "not real". Pretty stupid thing to do. Don't vote that something does not make sense unless you *understand* it (failure to understand means the opposite: it means don't vote).

Comment: thank you for the support on this post really want to get it resolved thank you :) elfenliedtopfan5

Comment: You want to replace a image in a dll file but that has already been done?